# JPA: EntityExistsException during persist method call

Tags: jpa, persist

I am experimenting a bit with JPA with OpenJPA as the provider.

I call:

```
em.persist()
```

on entity instance,and then call

```
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

If entity with same id is already there, persist() throws EntityExistsException.
But I see no SQL query being fired when persist() executes.Then how does provider knows that such an entity exists in DB?I think persist must surely talk to DB to know existence of the entity if it has to throw EntityExistsException.

Comment: or maybe it looked in the L1 cache? or the L2 cache?

Comment: ...but persistent context is the L1 cache, and it is managed by entity manager. L2 needs to be configured which I haven't.

Comment: they are the only places it can get it from ... L1, L2 or DB. So if you haven't set up L2 (it is disabled by default with OpenJPA?) then just L1 or DB, and you can check L1 yourself